# combining the Json data from two different processors in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I am working on one of the tasks in Nifi and I am stuck on of the issue, the issue is I am getting the Json data from jolt transforms processor and also I am getting the Json data from input port processor now the issue is I need to combine the data from two processor based on id’s.  How to combined the data from two processors based on common id ? Will you please help me out.

Thanks,

Sathish

Comment: welcome! What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by 'based on common id' ?

Comment: Hi guys @JonatanKruszewski  we have two different apis and we need to match hostid's  which is common between these two api outputs/results and conclude the data from these two apis based on the hostid's

Comment: @Sathish, Please edit your question and provide of initial data and expected result.

Comment: Hello @dagget, The flow is using invoke http processor I will fetch the data from api and inother part the data we are pulling from another api sending the data to ouput port, now using input port I am pulling the data and there is common field which is id, using the id from both apis we need to merge the data that  is requirement, I will tell you the flow.
Input
1st Api data :
id, Name, Value
2nd Api data:
id , attested_date, operational_status, dv_skip_sync, dv_sys_mod_count 

Expected output:
id, Name,Value,attested_date, operational_status,dv_skip_sync,dv_sys_mod_count

Comment: Hi Sathish , welcome to the community. @daggett requests you to edit your current question by clicking on the **Edit** button under the tags section, but not commenting here.